# Facebook PHP SDK - When I put this in a function, it doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, function, sdk, facebook-fql

When I put this code in a function (in functions.php) and echo it in my index file, it doesn't work.

```
<?php
//functions.php
include_once 'sdk/src/facebook.php';

function FB_GetProfilePic($user) {
   $fql    =   "SELECT pic_big FROM profile WHERE id = $user";
   $param  =   array(
       'method'     => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql
    );

   $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

    return $fqlResult[0]['pic_big'];

}
?>
```

But when I do this in the index file, it works.

```
<?php
//index.php

$fql    =   "SELECT pic_big FROM profile WHERE id = $user";
$param  =   array(
       'method'     => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql
);

$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

echo $fqlResult[0]['pic_big'];
```

}
?>

Comment: try echoing from the function instead of return

Comment: And check console for any errors..

Comment: @LiamAllan It doesn't work. :s

Comment: @Shadowfax I can't see the errors because my web host shows a custom error message for php errors. And I can't run it in localhost because of my app config's on Facebook

Comment: is the `$user` variable being passed to the function correctly? how are u calling the function?

Comment: [can’t see errors, can’t run on localhost] – well then set up a sensible development environment somehow – instead of “outsourcing” your debugging to SO!

Comment: I can see the phrase "it doesn't work" here three times, but no indication of (a) what it is meant to do, and (b) what actually happened. Can you be more specific? (Ah, I see you've fixed it - good. Please consider avoiding this phrase anyway - hopefully you can see why it is not very useful).

Comment: I'm marking as o/t as solutions involving undefined (or out of scope) variables are too localised to be useful as long-term questions. Pleased you fixed it though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your function `$facebook` is not declared. get a reference to it by either passing it to the function or using `global`